# How to connect an old sata disk to an external e-sata port without opening the case?

Tags: sata, esata, connector

I have an old sata disk that I don´t want to put inside my new PC, but I want to access it with it and copy some (big, fat) contents in there.

I have a case that has an e-sata port.

I want to connect my internal older sata hard disk to the external e-sata port.

I´ve looked for cables that connect sata to e-sata, but I´ve read that I still need another cable that connects the hard drive to the power.

Is there some cable or connector that can do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is use the power supply from a usb to hard drive adapter [similar to this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812119152)

I have done this many times when power is not available inside the case or other problem similar to yours.